# How to change title bar transparency in KDE Plasma 5?

Tags: kde, opensuse, theme, plasma

[image: transparent title bar]

Open SUSE Tumbleweed, very latest KDE

I played around with themes and things and can not find the settings anymore. Just read something (outdated I think) about manually editing files that define the color theme. I am pretty sure there was a slider or some way to set a color with alpha value for transparency somewhere, but I can not find it.

Comment: I'm digging around on Fedora KDE and can't find it either - is it maybe now burned into either the Global Theme or Plasma Style? (I have no experience tinkering with these)

Comment: I am going crazy over this. KDE has so many settings. It may have actually disappeared after an update or the setting in only visible with a specific color theme or window decoration and I downloaded a lot of them. But I never manually edited a file.

Comment: Such a setting is not available in KDE5 last time I checked. It was available in KDE 3.5 but ever since KDE4 it's been down to themes which either have some preconfigured transparency setting or none.

Comment: Check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1173618/how-to-make-kde-plasma-taskbar-panel-transparent It has some hacks to enable/configure transparency.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it not transparent again by downloading a global design called "Aritim Dark" and applying it. Maybe I remembered it wrong and some window decoration or other thing I downloaded had it hardcoded into the design. The issue was that it did not disappear on switching colors/decorations/other things.

Answer (score 0):

The title bar is part of the window decoration (in appearance settings), so you need a window decoration theme that has transparency. [Klassy](https://github.com/paulmcauley/klassy) is a fork of Breeze (the stock window decoration) that allows you to configure the transparency.

Answer (score -1):

There are few steps to enable transparency in KDE Plasma menus and title bars;

1. Open “System Settings”
2. Go to: Appearance > Application Style > Widget Style > Applications > Widget Style
3. Make sure “Breeze” is selected
4. Tap the “Configure” button
5. Choose the “Transparency” tab
6. Customize the slider to choose your desired amount of transparency.

Comment: There is *only* a slider for menu nothing else. So no this is not it. There are other transparency or opacity sliders for various things I found deep nested somewhere else, but they do not include title bars either. The menu transparency does not even work for me currently with the "Chrome OS Dark" theme I currently use. But I had it working b4 and did not like it always. I also experience bugs with the wrong windows decoration getting applied currently ... not always fun to run Tumleweed.